# Trying to Implement Email Verification using NodeJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, html

This is my sample code.. which works fine..  Named as server.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'XXXXXX',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // secure:true for port 465, secure:false for port 587
    auth: {
        user: 'XXXXXXX',
        pass: 'XXXXXXX'
    }
});

// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
    from: '"me " <aXXXXXXX.com>', // sender address
    to: 'XXXXXXXX.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Test Mail from ME using NodeJS', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ?', // plain text body
    html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
});
```

Using the above example i planned to implement using webpage.

This is modified one .. named as server1.js

```
var express=require('express');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var app=express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
/*
    Here we are configuring our SMTP Server details.
    STMP is mail server which is responsible for sending and recieving email.
*/
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'XXXXXX',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, //secure : true for 465, secure: false for port 587 
    auth: {
        user: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        pass: 'XXXXXXXXXX'
    }
});
var rand,mailOptions,host,link;
/*------------------SMTP Over-----------------------------*/

/*------------------Routing Started ------------------------*/

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.get('/send',function(req,res){
        rand=Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 54);
    host=req.get('host');
    link="http://"+req.get('host')+"/verify?id="+rand;
    mailOptions={
        to : req.query.to,
        subject : "Please confirm your Email account",
        html : "Hello,<br> Please Click on the link to verify your email.<br><a href="+link+">Click here to verify</a>" 
    }
    console.log(mailOptions);
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
     if(error){
            console.log(error);
        res.end("error");
     }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        res.end("sent");
         }
});
});

app.get('/verify',function(req,res){
console.log(req.protocol+":/"+req.get('host'));
if((req.protocol+"://"+req.get('host'))==("http://"+host))
{
    console.log("Domain is matched. Information is from Authentic email");
    if(req.query.id==rand)
    {
        console.log("email is verified");
        res.end("<h1>Email "+mailOptions.to+" is been Successfully verified");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("email is not verified");
        res.end("<h1>Bad Request</h1>");
    }
}
else
{
    res.end("<h1>Request is from unknown source");
}
});

/*--------------------Routing Over----------------------------*/

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Express Started on Port 3000");
});
```

Now Index.HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Node.JS Email application</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var from,to,subject,text;
    $("#send_email").click(function(){      
        to=$("#to").val();      
        $("#message").text("Sending E-mail...Please wait");
        $.get("/send",{to: to},function(data){
        if(data=="sent")
        {
            $("#message").empty().html("<p>Email is been sent at "+to+" . Please check inbox !</p>");
        }

});
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#container
{
    margin-left:400px;
    margin-top:50px;
}
#to,#subject,#content
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size:18px;
    width:530px;
}
h1
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size:40px; 
    color: #3b5998;
}
p
{
    color:green;
}
#send_email
{
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
#message
{
    font-size:18px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Email-verification System in Node.js</h1>
<input type="text" id="to" placeholder="Enter E-mail which you want to verify"><br>
<button id="send_email">Send Email</button><br>
<span id="message"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i enter the email and click send, it shows success message in webpage and as well as in console as well

But, i didn't receive any mail.. whereareas implementation of server.js works just fine..

I dont know what i am missing, kindly help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

just change the smtpTransport function by

```
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response)  {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.end("error");
    } else {
        console.log('Message sent: ' + response.message);
        res.end("sent");
    };
});
```

That should be works.

Comment: lemme try and getback to you

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that the email that is sent using nodemailer is blocked by email company such as 'GMAIL' as it cannot identify how secure the mail sent by the party is.

I faced a similar issue with nodemailer where I had to make a gmail user allow emails from untrusted parties.

Comment: In server.js, gmail also works fine since i changed option allow secure apps.. moreover am not using gmail for mailing purpose, have some private hoster for that.. that too works fine with server.js

Answer (score 0):

Some domains like GMail block unknown domains. I also faced the same issue when sending mails to GMail using Mailgun's API in nodejs.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to make sure of

1. **Allow less secure apps is turned on.**

click on this link
[less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/security)

image -
[less secure apps - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPWYl.png)

2. **You're using app password instead of your real password.**

app password will look like this 'caccfssrbxgzvmabb'

to generate one you'll need to have 2 factor authentication enabled.

here is the link for it
[Two Factor Authentication](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/signinoptions/two-step-verification/enroll-welcome)

after this is done you'll be getting app password option like the one in the image below

[App Password - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmPmu.png)

generate a new password and use that in your configuration file.

This is the configuration i used for gmail account.

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, //secure : true for 465, secure: false for port 587 
    auth: {
        user: '{{email}}',
        pass: '{{app_password}}'
    }
});
```

NOTE: In my case i also used CORS. please have a check on that too if needed.

here is the link for it - [CORS NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)